# How to get fixture of Custom shape body?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I just want to ask that I have my custom shape physical body, let say, I have a STAR having four outside and four inside vertices, and made with Physics Editor.

By using that Plist generated by Physics Editor, the body shows and behaving just perfect, but problem is that I could not get fixture(s) of that custom shape to get collision detection or any thing else.

So, how could I get the fixture(s) of custom physical shape body made with physics editor, so I can detect collision?

P.S: I have MyContactListener class that is working fine with basic shapes like circle and line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? show us the code that won't work repectively where you need to access the fixture. If the shape isn't colliding check body's bit maska and categories.

Comment: you read this tutorial. [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14302/how-to-make-a-game-like-fruit-ninja-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-1)

Comment: I am checking collision as mentioned in
http://www.raywenderlich.com/28606/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-part-2
so, in update, if I am checking a groundBody fixture, that is basically a "b2EdgeShape" and a circle i.e. "b2CircleShape", then it is working perfect. but if I have a STAR shape body, then only one outer vertex of STAR is detecting, but not all vertices.

Some where I found this code,

for (b2Fixture* f = _malletBody->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext())

but what if I have two custom shapes, then have to nested this loop, which will be heavy?